# How to run multiple background tasks at a specific time interval?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, background-service, background-task

I'm developing an application in C# MVC and I want to execute multiple background tasks each at different time intervals. I already have a service that inherits the class BackgroundService.

[I already tried following this tutorial](https://medium.com/medialesson/run-and-manage-periodic-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core-6-with-c-578a31f4b7a3), but that only works if u only have 1 task.

Do you need a separate service for each task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you need a separate service for each task?

There are multiple options here:

- The official documentation shows the option to create a [Timed background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks):

  ```
  public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
  {
       private int executionCount = 0;
       private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
       private Timer? _timer = null;

       public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
       {
           _logger = logger;
       }

       public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

           _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
               TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }

       private void DoWork(object? state)
       {
           var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

           _logger.LogInformation(
               "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
       }

       public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

           _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           _timer?.Dispose();
       }
  }
  ```

  You can use this approach with several timers.
- You can just start several tasks in the `ExecuteAsync`:

  ```
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
       await Task.WhenAll(Job1(stoppingToken), Job2(stoppingToken));
  }

  public async Task Job1(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
       using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(period1);
       while (
           !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Work1");
       }
  }

  public async Task Job2(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
       using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(period2);
       while (
           !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Work2");
       }
  }
  ```
- Use different hosted services, one per task (personally my go to option in this case)
- Also consider switching some scheduling libraries/frameworks like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do u also know how I could make both tasks run once at startup and then via the intervals?

Comment: @Lenny you move the "iteration" logic into separate method  and call it at the start before starting the intervals (in `ExecuteAsync` or `StartAsync`) depending on the case.

Comment: this works but I don't understand why haha, does the executeAsync method only execute at startup of the app? how does it then still do the intervals?

Comment: @Lenny was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to upvote and accept it (checkmark to the left). As for how it works - basically yes, execute is called only once - see the [`BackgroundService` implementation](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs,40).